# Libraw is making my images too bright compared to nikons own converter

Tags: c++, opencv, libraw

It seems that nikons own tool and photoshop has the option to open the image as they was taken.

but using libraws dcraw processor I cant figure this out.

here is my implementation.

```
CV_EXPORTS_W int load_image(const char * path, cv::Mat & output)
{


    LibRaw RawProcessor;

    int ret;

#define imgD RawProcessor.imgdata

    imgD.params.use_camera_wb = 1;
    imgD.params.use_auto_wb = 0;

    if ((ret = RawProcessor.open_file(path)) != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, path, libraw_strerror(ret));
        return -1;
    }
    if ((ret = RawProcessor.unpack()) != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
    {

        return -1;
    }

    int check = RawProcessor.dcraw_process();
    libraw_processed_image_t *image_ptr = RawProcessor.dcraw_make_mem_image(&check);
                
    output = cv::Mat(cv::Size(image_ptr->width, image_ptr->height), CV_8UC3, image_ptr->data, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
    cv::cvtColor(output, output, 4);
}
```

Updated with an image to show what I am talking about:
The images are being normalized somehow. If the original image contains a large area of light matrial the overall image becomes more dark. I want to be able to just read the raw image data and normalize or handle it my own way in opencv.

[image]

### update

Based on comments I got the brightness adjusted but a problem now arize with the pixel color values, best seen here:

[image]

The image on the left is the result of libraw and the right one is viewnx.
There seem to be some noise colors in the libraw image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

raw data is stored in LibRaw::rawdata.raw_image[] array. These values are 'as RAW as possible' without black subtraction and/on de-bayer (demosaic) applied.

To access this data you need to call LibRaw::open_file() and LibRaw::unpack.

Also, you may exclude some steps from data processing on LibRaw::dcraw_process():

```
 imgdata.params.no_interpolation=1 disables demosaic
 imgdata.params.no_auto_scale=1 disables scaling from camera maximum to 64k
 imgdata.params.no_auto_bright=1 disables auto brighten
```

Comment: Going to try that and mark as answer if it works. THanks

Comment: The image is almost all black after using these 3. same code as in the question with your added parameter. Also the cvtColor is just doing BGR to RGB if thats not clear.

Comment: that makes sense as the demosaic is disabled. The goal is to make the image look as they was taken (the thumbnail in the nef ect, also how nikons own tool extract jpgs)

Comment: The 'exactly as taken' is RAW data.
JPEG is postprocessed (white balance, demosaiced, tone curve applied, color converted from camera space to sRGB or whatever).

LibRaw do not use any camera settings by default: WB is daylight and brightness is adjusted to have 1% saturated pixels.

Comment: I am at this point trying to extrac the RAW data and do a cv::COLOR_BayerBG2RGB conversion in openCV such I know no white balance, tone curve normalization have been done. We take images with 70% overlap from a plane and I want to do these changes based on the neighbour images also and not just the internal information of an image. Kinda want to do an image stiching and then apply all the tone curve and white balance changes.

Comment: after unpack and accessing imgD.rawdata.raw_image for the raw data, i also need the size to to create my Cv::Mat, but none of the sizes in imgD.rawdata.sizes fits the size of the image. How do I get the real size?

Comment: also tried use_camera_wb=1 and no_auto_bright=1 which is what gives the best result sofar. but that is to dark compared.

Comment: 1) Today cameras are underexpose heavily (typical graypoint value is 7-10% instead of 18% graypoint). So, if use_camera_wb/auto_bright give you good direction, you may try to use positive exposure correction together with highlights compression.
Try something like
     
    params.exp_correc=1; 
    params.exp_shift=2.0; 
    params.exp_preser=1.0;

2) After LibRaw::unpack() the imgdata.rawdata.sizes is exactly the same as imgdata.sizes.
Use raw_pitch (in bytes!) as row pitch, raw_width/raw_height as image sizes.

Comment: 1) We are moving in the correct direction, image is now something like 5% darker compared to 25% darker (my impression). 2) I think Nikon Nef  raw formats are storing data 2pixel/3bytes for E800 and opencv seems to only support CV_U16 for the Bayer to RGB.

Comment: imgD.params.exp_shift = 4.0; is giving very very close to same result for my test image as viewNX do. Now I will do a large test on many images. If nikon know this stuff when exporting the image, and it is different for each camera, would we not be able to read that information somewhere what kind of exposure correction to use.

Comment: exp_shift из +2EV correction.

Yes, it is different for different cameras, very depends on exposure meter calibration

Comment: do you maybe have any sugestion to the updated questions. Seems that the colors are not as clear as my target output.

Comment: created a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439587/my-libraw-decoded-images-contains-noise

Comment: I can't express how much headache your answer saved me. `no_interpolation` isn't in the docs as far as I can tell, and that flag was exactly what I wished I had. Thanks so much!